# Is there an approximation function for this function?

Tags: approximation, approximation-theory, linear-approximation, approximate-integration

The function is:
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x}{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{1+y}\right)}$$
where $x\in [0,1], y \in [0,1] $,and the approximation function can split $x$ and $y$.

The result is like this:$f(x,y) = f_1(x)+f_2(y)$.

Comment: might be obvious, but you can always do a Taylor expansion

Comment: @Chris Thanks,but Taylor expansion can't split $x$ and $y$ like the form of   $f_1(x)+f_2(y)$.

Comment: @Mark Viola Thanks for your editing.

Comment: why not? $$f(x_0+x, y_0+y)=f(x_0,y_0)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)\cdot x+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)\cdot y+\mathcal{O}(||x,y||^2)$$

Comment: @Chris Thanks,I have misunderstand it....